# Clear/Reset Syncfusion gridcontrol clipboard

Tags: syncfusion

In one of my application I have syncfusion gridcontrol.

After doing a paste operation (CutPaste.Paste()) I would like to clear or reset the gridcontrol clipboard.

Is there any way I could perform this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Syncfusion products.

In order to clear the contents of the clipboard, use `Clipboard.Clear()` method in the ClipboardPasted event. This event will trigger after the pasting  is done. Please refer to the below code and sample,

```cs
// Event Subscription  
gridControl1.Model.ClipboardPasted += Model_ClipboardPasted;  

// Event Customization  
private void Model_ClipboardPasted(object sender, 
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridCutPasteEventArgs e)  
{  
    Clipboard.Clear();  
}
```

Sample Link: [GridControlSample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13DCERFNqucGrr9PYogMEwbWdDro_y6qb/view?usp=sharing)